# Google Authentication for Oracle ADF Application

Tags: google-api, glassfish-3, oracle-adf, google-openid, google-oauth

I am using Oracle ADF Essentials with Glassfish server. How to authorize users against their google account. I came across [Google OAuth API](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2) . How do I go about with Google's OAuth2 using Oracle ADF. After authentication I would also need to access the user's youtube profile (like uploading videos under his profile, get the user uploaded youtube video), thats later, I need authentication first ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is authentication, see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

That’s at the REST level; the Google APIs java library takes care of this at a higher level: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/